# Check constraint based on information in another table

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

Given two tables:

**TableA**

```
(
    id : primary key, 
    type : tinyint, 
    ...
)
```

**TableB**

```
(
    id : primary key, 
    tableAId : foreign key to TableA.id,
    ...
)
```

There is a check constraint on TableA.type with permitted values of (0, 1, 2, 3). All other values are forbidden.

Due to the known limitations, records in TableB can exist only when TableB.TableAId references the record in TableA with TableA.type=0, 1 or 2 but not 3. The latter case is forbidden and leads the system into an invalid state.

How can I guarantee that in such case the insert to TableB will fail?

Comment: One way http://stackoverflow.com/a/21198681/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith looks acceptable, but way over-engineered.
Instead of additional view on TableA and TableB with unique constraint it could be better to write a before-trigger or something similar to check constraint in case such features are supported by mssql server

Comment: You could do it with triggers. You would need to write triggers on both table A and table B and be responsible for ensuring that they operate correctly under all conditions. [Such as snapshot isolation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/21/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-1.aspx). The indexed view leaves it to the engine to enforce.

Comment: well, you're right. Indexed (or check-constrained) view is a better solution. Maybe you could write an answer for me to check it as correct one?

Answer (score 4):

Cross-table constraint using an empty indexed view:

#### Tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA 
(
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [type] tinyint NOT NULL 
        CHECK ([type] IN (0, 1, 2, 3))
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB 
(
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    tableAId integer NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.TableA
);
```

#### The 'constraint view'

```sql
-- This view is always empty (limited to error rows)
CREATE VIEW dbo.TableATableBConstraint
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT
    Error = 
        CASE 
            -- Error condition: type = 3 and rows join
            WHEN TA.[type] = 3 AND TB.id = TA.id
            -- For a more informative error
            THEN CONVERT(bit, 'TableB cannot reference type 3 rows in TableA.')
            ELSE NULL
        END
FROM dbo.TableA AS TA
JOIN dbo.TableB AS TB
    ON TB.id = TA.id
WHERE
    TA.[type] = 3;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cuq 
ON dbo.TableATableBConstraint (Error);
```

[Online demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68d5bcec8f21d8c7480f0cd216e85b46)

```sql
-- All succeed
INSERT dbo.TableA (id, [type]) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT dbo.TableA (id, [type]) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT dbo.TableA (id, [type]) VALUES (3, 3);

INSERT dbo.TableB 
    (id, tableAId) 
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2);

-- Fails
INSERT dbo.TableB (id, tableAId) VALUES (3, 3);

-- Fails
UPDATE dbo.TableA SET [type] = 3 WHERE id = 1;
```

This is similar in concept to the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198681) to [Check constraints that ensures the values in a column of tableA is less the values in a column of tableB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21197343), but this solution is self-contained (does not require a separate table with more than one row at all times). It also produces a more informational error message, for example:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TableB cannot reference type 3 rows in TableA.' to data type bit.

#### Important notes

The error condition **must be completely specified** in the `CASE` expression to ensure correct operation in all cases. Do not be tempted to omit conditions implied by the rest of the statement. In this example, it would be an error to omit `TB.id = TA.id` (implied by the join).

The SQL Server query optimizer is free to reorder predicates, and makes no general guarantees about the timing or number of evaluations of scalar expressions. In particular, [scalar computations can be deferred](https://sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html).

*Completely* specifying the error condition(s) within a `CASE` expression ensures the complete set of tests is evaluated together, and no earlier than correctness requires. From an execution plan perspective, this means the *Compute Scalar* associated with the `CASE` tests will appear on the indexed view delta maintenance branch:

[image: execution plan]

The light shaded area highlights the indexed view maintenance region; the Compute Scalar containing the `CASE` expression is dark-shaded.

Comment: Ohh clever... Gives you a weird conversion errror, but at least you do get the error message. Looks a bit dangerous given the risk of optimizations, you can't *always* be sure of the order of `Compute Scalar` can you? I once had a divide by zero on an indexed view for exactly that reason